# Может ли гостиница быть "дешевой"?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Может ли гостиница быть "дешевой", или все-таки эпитет правильнее применить к отдельному номеру? Я имею в виду литературный текст, а не текст рекламного объявления.

Answer (score 3):

Признак переносится с номеров на гостиницу. Этот прием называется   метонимией.

В Нацкорпусе нашлось 31 вхождение. Примеры:

> Они спаивали матросов и заставляли их в пьяном виде подписывать кабальные контракты с капитанами; список недобросовестных татуировщиков, адреса пивных в главных портах земного шара, где принимали в залог матросские вещи, адреса «бордингаузов» (**дешевых гостиниц** для моряков), где постояльцам не давали покоя «братья» и «сестры» из Армии спасения. [К. Г. Паустовский. Повесть о жизни. Время больших ожиданий (1958)]
>
> До сих пор кровать чаще всего служит японцу лишь во время его свадебного путешествия, когда он останавливается в туристских отелях, а в дальнейшем ― во время его любовных похождений вне семейного очага, потому что **дешевые гостиницы**, сдающие комнаты на два часа с платой вперед, также обставлены в Японии кроватями. [Всеволод Овчинников. Ветка сакуры (1971)]
>
> Надо бы на квартиру скорей переехать, ― задумчиво оглядывая грязные обои **дешевой гостиницы**, где на первое время остановились Арсеньевы, говорила Марина. [Валентина Осеева. Динка (1959)]

В литературном тексте любое место, где цены низкие, может быть названо дешевым: дешевая гостиница, дешевая парикмахерская, дешевый магазин.

Comment: А не разговорное ли это выражение "дешевый магазин"? Ведь правильно (литературно) - магазин низких цен. Так ведь и до "дешевой цены" можно дойти...

Comment: @Виктор, По-моему, и дешевая гостиница — сниженный стиль. Это же литературное произведение, а не доклад, для которого  "магазин низких цен" лучше подойдет.

Comment: А вот "дешевая цена" — просто безграмотно, на мой взглад (хотя есть такие, кто пытается эту безграмотность узаконить). Есть разница между сниженным стилем и распространенной ошибкой.

Comment: То есть, все-таки это не метонимия, а разговорный стиль, который не применим даже к низкосортному литературному тексту...? (А только к газетному объявлению и дорожному указателю).

Comment: @Виктор, Вы преувеличиваете. В Нацкопрусе "дешевая гостиница" найдена 31 раз. Паустовский — не слишком низкосортный литератор, на Ваш взгляд? *Они спаивали матросов и заставляли их в пьяном виде подписывать кабальные контракты с капитанами; список недобросовестных татуировщиков, адреса пивных в главных портах земного шара, где принимали в залог матросские вещи, адреса «бордингаузов» (дешевых гостиниц для моряков), где постояльцам не давали покоя «братья» и «сестры» из Армии спасения. [К. Г. Паустовский. Повесть о жизни. Время больших ожиданий (1958)] *

Comment: @Виктор, Кстати, "магазин дешевых товаров" — это корректно,  а не  "магазин низких цен".

Comment: Насчет магазина низких цен подтвердить документально не могу, а вот "Аптека низких цен" у нас в городе имеется. А "Магазин дешевых товаров" - так никто не говорит и вывеску своей лавки таким эпитетом никто не украшает, поскольку в бытовой речи слово "дешевый" иногда означает "плохой" Например: "дешевые стихи", "дешевый человек", "дешевка" и т. д. https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/дешёвка  Кстати и "дешевая гостиница" в разговорной речи может восприниматься как плохая (с клопами).

Comment: @Виктор! Дешевый — он, как правило, потому и дешев, что  качеством ниже. Поэтому да,  "дешевая гостиница" понимается как плохая, также дешевая колбаса и все дешевое.  А в аптеке, думаю, продаются обычные лекарства, а не их дешевые аналоги, просто цены ниже, поэтому  "Аптека низких цен". В любом случае, для рекламы слово "дешевый" не подходит, Вы правы.

Comment: @Виктор! Вернемся к Вашему вопросу. У вас литературный текст. Тут вопрос может быть о том, какое отношение к гостинице хочет выразить автор.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8JNs0VusWKA  Мой сюжет, наглядно демонстрирующий, "какое отношение к гостинице хочет выразить автор". (Койко-место стоит $1,5)

Answer (score 1):

Может ли гостиница быть дешевой?
Конечно может!
Вот пример, в котором данное сочетание вполне уместно:

> Мой знакомый бизнесмен выкупает у владельцев нерентабельные гостинцы, наводит в них порядок и продает по более высокой цене. Недавно он нашел одну достаточно **дешевую гостинцу** и сейчас обсуждает с ее владельцем условия купли-продажи.

Надеюсь, из этого примера вполне понятно, почему словосочетание "дешевая гостиница" не совсем однозначно. Именно поэтому, я бы применял его с осторожностью.

Comment: Тогда и парикмахерская может быть дешевой, если ее выкупить под ресторан; и магазин - аналогично. А уж цена - тем более... если "цена" - это, к примеру, сорт сказочных фруктов. :-)

Comment: @Виктор, многие слова и словосочетания могут иметь сразу несколько возможных значений. Именно в зависимости от целей повествования (прояснить все максимально четко или, наоборот, создать двусмысленность) и нужно принимать решение о целесообразности их использования. Главное знать о том, что они неоднозначны, и применять (или не применять) такие слова осознанно.